# How can I include this swift declaration only before iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I have the following declaration in my AppDelegate.swift file.

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

and I want to include it only when the deployment target is set to below iOS 13.0. I have looked at

```
@available(...)
```

attribute but I don't think it can do what I want. Essentially I want to be able to build my project for iOS 12 or iOS 13 with the minimum number of changes to my project in AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift. I have made changes already to AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift using `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` and `#available(iOS 13.0, *)` but I still need to be able to exclude this other declaration when the deployment target is above iOS 12.

Here is my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow? // only include for builds < iOS 13.0
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {                          
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {     
            window = UIWindow() // only include for builds < iOS 13.0
            window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController()) // only include for builds < iOS 13.0
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible() // only include for builds < iOS 13.0      
        } 
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

and here is my SceneDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    // ...
}
```

Essentially all I want to have happen is I just change the deployment target and the appropriate bits of code get included or excluded in the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var window: UIWindow? // only include for builds < iOS 13.0
```

Just leave the declaration alone. On iOS 12 and before it will refer to the app window. On iOS 13 and later it will be nil and no harm done.